# Does Ubuntu work properly on a laptop HP Pavilion 15 -CD006LA?

Tags: hp, compatibility, hp-pavilion

I'm thinking to buy a HP laptop model pavilion 15 -CD006LA, to install Ubuntu, but I read that there are some problems with Ubuntu on HP laptops.

Do you have any information about this?
Is it recommended to buy a HP laptop, or should I buy one from another company?

I hope that you can provide me some arguments for and against...

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are not problems with Ubuntu. In my personal experience I only had a problem, with skylake architecture of Intel. It was solved coping two works in kernel line. I left behind others OS because of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but failed with my HP Pavilion laptop. I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04; the lighter version offered without including non-ubuntu software. There was a failure to stay online with wifi and a crazy random rotation of the display, as if it was a smartphone being tipped sideways. The same disc used in a Toshiba laptop is working as it should. In fact that's where I am now, running Ubuntu from the disc.